Unable to start kafka Server on Windows
I was trying to start kafka Server after i started zookeeper but i run in some error. I have downloaded zookeeper from the downloadpage and i could sucessfully start it, because when i try to start zookeeper from kafka installation i get a syntax error by cmd. However the same problem when i try to start kafka server, i get the following output:
C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
Syntaxfehler.
C:\kafka>
I have set the enviroment variables to: KAFKA_HOME C:\kafka  and the path to: C:\kafka\bin\windows
and i set the server.properties to: log.dirs=c:/kafka/kafka-logs
i use the java version java version "1.8.0_411"
I would be thankfull for any help
I was trying to run kafka from powershell but same syntax error...

I do not think cmd supports the syntax .\bin . Could you try following the exactly the guide available at https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart?

Latest kafka should use Java 17, but I don't think that's the issue. It's just not tested very much in windows, and using WSL2 or Docker would work better

I used your link but this documentation is for linux systems, i´ve allready been to this site and was downloading kafka from there, this commands dosn´t work on windows
